# Derivative of norm

Tags: matrices, derivatives, normed-spaces, frobenius-method

What is the partial derivative of this expression with respect to T:

$$‖X−PTV‖^2$$
Where ∥.∥ is the Frobenius norm, and X,P, T and V are matrices.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y = (PTV-X)$, then
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= \|Y\|_F^2 = Y:Y \cr
d\phi &= 2Y:dY = 2Y:P\,dT\,V = 2P^TYV^T:dT \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial T}&= 2P^TYV^T = 2P^T(PTV-X)V^T \cr
}$$
where colon (:) denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$